# unable to print the username onto console in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have a html file with a linked js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/cart.js' %}">
  var user= '{{request.user}}'
</script>
```

and in cart.js i am trying to print the user variable
but i keep getting an error saying uncaught ReferenceError user is not defined.
any ideas on how to resolve this?
this is cart.js

```
var updateBtns=document.getElementsByClassName("update-cart")
for(var i=0;i<updateBtns.length;i++){
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        var pid=this.dataset.item
        var action=this.dataset.action
        console.log('pid:',pid,'action:',action)
    })
    console.log('USER',user)
    if(user=='AnonymousUser'){
        console.log('Not logged in')

    }else{
        console.log('User is logged in')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [w3 organization](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT), if a `<script>` tag has a `src="…"` attribute, the *content* of the script is ignored, so it will never evaluate `var user= …`. You should work with two tags:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/cart.js' %}"/>
<script>
  var user = '{{request.user}}';
</script>
```

if `js/cart.js` needs to user the `user` variable, you need to define that first, so:

```
<script>
  var user = '{{request.user}}';
</script>
<script src="{% static 'js/cart.js' %}"/>
```

Comment: i've tried what you've suggested but the error persists

Comment: @SaketVempaty: does `js/cart.js` uses the `user` variable?

Comment: yes it does use the user variable and the error is still persisting after defining the user variable first too

Comment: @SaketVempaty: take a look in the browser console where the error is raised and what script thus needs `user` before it is defined.

Comment: console.log('USER',user) is the statement which needs the user variable

Comment: @SaketVempaty: where is that statment defined...

Comment: have added code for cart.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251158/discussion-between-saket-vempaty-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add a breakpoint in your browser debugger in the line

```
var user=...
```

and reload the page.
Thus you can see if the line is executed before the card.js script.